# Batch script: avoid infinite file loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

Running the following batch script, I get an infinite loop even when all files are moved into the destination folder. I get the message: "The system cannot find the file specified" at each iteration.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
cd .\IMPORT
set nlot=0
:beginfor
set count=0
set /a nlot=%nlot%+1
FOR /R  "." %%A IN (Zango_Sku_*.xml) DO (
    IF NOT EXIST .\lot%nlot% mkdir .\lot%nlot%
    move .\%%~nxA .\lot%nlot%\%%~nxA 
    set /a count=!count!+1
    IF !count! EQU 2000 goto :beginfor
)
```

Comment: You are using a recursive search for files in current directory and below, and moving the files to folders under the current folder, so, the same files are found again by the search operation inside the new folder, moved again, found again, moved again, ....

Comment: 1. Instead of `move ...` try `echo move ...`; you will see why `file not found` error occurs (try `echo %%A` as well). 2.  @MCND is right, use `for /f` against `dir /b /s`  instead of `for /R`

Comment: Thank you for your help ! I just removed the /R and it works !